# How to have the Character count non-visable when retuning to a page in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, textview

So I have it set up when the character count shows when the corresponding EditText box is of focus. And not visible when the user clicks somewhere else. but when I go into a different page and then come back to the previous page, all the character count fields pop up, but then it functions back once you click on each individual field. So I would like for those character fields to stay non-visible when I return to the page from a different page.

So here's the code that's controlling the Character Count TextView.

```
/** Having the Character Count Box observe the state of the corresponding EditText Box*/
            itemView.date_time_add.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
                if (!hasFocus) itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.GONE
                else itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            itemView.cable_run_add.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
                if (!hasFocus) itemView.cCount2.visibility = View.GONE
                else itemView.cCount2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            itemView.entrance_add.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
                if (!hasFocus) itemView.cCount3.visibility = View.GONE
                else itemView.cCount3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            itemView.door_lock_add.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
                if (!hasFocus) itemView.cCount4.visibility = View.GONE
                else itemView.cCount4.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            itemView.handicap_operator_add.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
                if (!hasFocus) itemView.cCount5.visibility = View.GONE
                else itemView.cCount5.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            /** A custom character count feature with an EditText and TextView */
            itemView.date_time_add.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.GONE
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    if (s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.GONE
                    } else {
                        itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    if (!s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount1.text = "${255 - s.length} Characters Remaining"
                    }
                    else {
                        itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }

            })

            itemView.cable_run_add.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    itemView.cCount2.text = ""
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    if (s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount2.visibility = View.GONE
                    } else {
                        itemView.cCount2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    if (!s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount2.text = "${255 - s.length} Characters Remaining"
                    }
                    else{
                        itemView.cCount2.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }

            })

            itemView.entrance_add.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    itemView.cCount3.text = ""
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    if (s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount3.visibility = View.GONE
                    } else {
                        itemView.cCount3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    if (!s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount3.text = "${255 - s.length} Characters Remaining"
                    }
                    else {
                        itemView.cCount3.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }

            })

            itemView.door_lock_add.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    itemView.cCount4.text = ""
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    if (s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount4.visibility = View.GONE
                    } else {
                        itemView.cCount4.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    if (!s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount4.text = "${1200 - s.length} Characters Remaining"
                    }
                    else {
                        itemView.cCount4.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }

            })

            itemView.handicap_operator_add.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    itemView.cCount5.text = ""
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    if (s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount5.visibility = View.GONE
                    } else {
                        itemView.cCount5.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    if (!s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount5.text = "${1200 - s.length} Characters Remaining"
                    }
                    else {
                        itemView.cCount5.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }

            })

        }
    }
```

For clarification:
I want to achieve having the character count TextView to be non-visible when I return to that fragment that has them. For example. I am filling out a form that has the character count in it, I go to a different fragment, then come back to the fragment that has the form and the character count is now visible. I want to character count TextView to be invisible when i return to that fragment.

[image]

*having the character count invisible when the user returns to this fragment.

Any sugestions is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't too far off from the solution. First setting up the `onFocusChangeListener` properly

```
itemView.date_time_add.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
                if (!hasFocus) itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                else itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
```

Here, instaded of `View.GONE`, I used `View.INVISIBLE` That seemed to work best. Then I made some changes to the `addTextChangeListener.

```
itemView.date_time_add.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }

                @SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    if (s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    } else {
                        if (itemView.date_time_add.hasFocus())
                        itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    if (!s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        itemView.cCount1.text = "${255 - s.length} Characters Remaining"
                    }
                    else {
                        itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    }
                }

            })
```

So instead of having checking for an empty string, I used `isNullOrEmpty` to check if there are characters in the String. Then changed all the visibility calls that were `View.GONE` to `View.INVISIBLE` and that's how I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if understanding well. What you want to achieve is that when you "go into a different page" (you mean an Activity?) you expect some special behavior in the new one? If it is the case, I assume that you are using an intent for that. Then you can simply add an extra String in the Activity opened and check for the String and do something.

Example:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", "exampleValue"); //Optional parameters
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then in NextActivity you can get the "key" value like:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key"); //if it's a string you stored

if (value.equals("exampleValue")
// do some work
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to achieve having the character count be non-visible when I return to that fragment that has them. For example. I am filling out a form that has the character count in it, I go to a different fragment, then come back to the fragment that has the form and the character count is now visible. I want to character count textview to be invisible when i return to that fragment.

Comment: Start the TextView of the char count as invisible or gone and show visible on focus. When you enter the activity the counter will be invisible. Also set it invisible on onResume to control what happen when you come back with back button.

Comment: How would you call the views on the Adapter to the onResume function?